# Logstash can't create index in elasticsearch for metricbeat file output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-5, metricbeat

I am trying to ingest metricbeat file output through logstash but logstash is not creating any index in elasticsearch. Below is my logstash .conf file

```
  input {
          file {
            type => "my-metricbeat"
            path => ["C:/tmp/metricbeat/metric*"]
            codec => "json"
            start_position => beginning
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
          }
         }
        output {
          if([type] == "my-metricbeat") {
              elasticsearch {
                hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
                index => "metricbeat-test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
              }
}
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
         }
```

ELK version is 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I see a missing bracket in your output.

Comment: that was a miss...but the issue still persists.

Comment: Did you add the index in your Kibana from the index pattern, under management ? Also, are you getting any errors in your LS logs, just to make sure you are not missing anything in your filter ?  bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test_pipeline.conf --config.test_and_exit   Use this to verify that your config file is OK and doesn't have major errors.

Comment: Yes, I have added index in Kibana from management console. I have installed ELK stack on the windows machine and I don't see any LS logs inside LS folder. I am pushing metricbeat output to file at "C:/tmp/metricbeat/metricbeat" location and trying to ingest this file directly in LS to create index in ES. LS doesn't create any index in ES on reading the metricbeat file output.

Comment: Not sure if you were able to resolve this issue yet. Sorry for not getting back earlier. The issue here maybe that you need a filter block even if empty. I had and issue before and it was similar so your config file would look like this: input { } filter { } output { }  -- leave your filter body empty, if not doing any grok filtering or other work inside.